# Ruby/Rails string memory leak - database strings are worst offenders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I've been battling what appears to be a memory leak in my Rails application for some time now. I *think* I've tracked part of the problem to a certain class, but I am seeing confusing results from `memory-profiler`.

Short background - the `AuditMessage` class constructs user-friendly strings based on the data in an audit log record (from the `audited` gem). This message is constructed when the audit record is created so it is run very often. My first test was to [benchmark-memory](https://github.com/michaelherold/benchmark-memory) to confirm that auditing and message generation was the problem:

```
Full audit with AuditMessage:   91 M memsize, 8.7 M retained
Without AuditMessage:           59 M memsize, 4.5 M retained
Without auditing at all:        33.8 M memsize; 2.9 M retained
```

That tells me that the auditing and `AuditMessage` are problematic. I created a short test file based on [this debugging article](https://samsaffron.com/archive/2015/03/31/debugging-memory-leaks-in-ruby). Essentially, I'm generating 100 messages, running Garbage Collection, checking memory, and repeating.

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = 'production'
require 'objspace'
require 'memory_profiler'
require File.expand_path("../config/environment", __FILE__)

def rss
  `ps -eo pid,rss | grep #{Process.pid} | awk '{print $2}'`.to_i
end

AuditMessage.new(AuditEntry.first).text_message

GC.start
puts "rss: #{rss} live objects #{GC.stat[:heap_live_slots]}"

MemoryProfiler.start
AuditEntry.limit(1000).in_groups_of(100) do |entries|
  entries.each do |a|
    AuditMessage.new(a).text_message
  end
  GC.start
  puts "rss: #{rss} live objects #{GC.stat[:heap_live_slots]}, total allocated: #{GC.stat[:total_allocated_objects]}"

end
puts "FINAL: rss: #{rss} live objects #{GC.stat[:heap_live_slots]}, total allocated: #{GC.stat[:total_allocated_objects]}"

report = MemoryProfiler.stop
report.pretty_print
```

I believe the `GC.stat` results confirm this is a memory leak because the `heap_live_slots` continue to increase. Please correct me if I'm wrong:

```
rss: 181688 live objects 572803
rss: 273484 live objects 631408, total allocated: 5307067
rss: 275464 live objects 654608, total allocated: 5743585
rss: 275468 live objects 677286, total allocated: 6180094
rss: 275468 live objects 698909, total allocated: 6618187
rss: 275476 live objects 722677, total allocated: 7066883
rss: 275476 live objects 745892, total allocated: 7509013
rss: 278512 live objects 771616, total allocated: 7955413
rss: 278992 live objects 794085, total allocated: 8368117
rss: 278992 live objects 815336, total allocated: 8763087
rss: 314976 live objects 852800, total allocated: 9319171
FINAL: rss: 315884 live objects 852790, total allocated: 9319200
```

I expected that the results from `MemoryProfiler` would show string leaks from my `AuditMessage` class. However, the results point towards `database_statments` and other activerecord internals. For example, the largest retained string objects are from activerecord:

```
Retained String Report
-----------------------------------
   886  "User"
   886  /Users/jackcollins/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:111

   782  "Activity"
   778  /Users/jackcollins/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:111
     1  /Users/jackcollins/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.0.1/lib/active_model/naming.rb:148
     1  /Users/jackcollins/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:124
     1  /Users/jackcollins/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:69
     1  /Users/jackcollins/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.0.5/lib/concurrent/collection/map/non_concurrent_map_backend.rb:24
```

By location also points to ActiveRecord and ActiveModel:

```
retained memory by location
-----------------------------------
1128000  /Users/jackcollins/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/result.rb:117
 943634  /Users/jackcollins/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:111
  45718  /Users/jackcollins/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.0.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:383
  20072  /Users/jackcollins/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:238
```

And finally:

```
retained memory by gem
-----------------------------------
2286378  activerecord-5.0.0.1
  54151  activesupport-5.0.0.1
  51342  activemodel-5.0.0.1
```

How should I interpret this data? Has anyone else run into a similar issue with string memory leaks in Ruby/Rails?